# Uniform Continuity of $f(x) = x+\frac1x$ on $(0,\infty)$ for any fixed $c>0$?

Tags: analysis

Let $f(x) = x+\frac1x$. Show that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$ for any fixed $c>0$?

Comment: Can you precise what is $c$?

Comment: Do you mean $[c,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I suppose you mean $x\in[c,\infty)$
$$|\frac{1}{x}+x-\frac{1}{y}-y|=|1-\frac{1}{xy}||x-y|\leq (1+\frac{1}{xy})|x-y|\leq(1+\frac{1}{c^2})|x-y|$$

Hence $f(x)$ is Lipschitz, hence uniformly continuous.